# Training multiple model in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Can I train multiple model in AWS Sagemaker by evaluating the models is train.py script and also how to get back multiple metrics from multiple models?

Any links, docs or videos would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you write in a sagemaker training script (assuming you use something that lets you pass custom code like your own container or a framework container) is flexible, and does not need to be just one model or even ML. You can definitely write multiple model trainings in a single container, and pull all related metrics using SageMaker metric capture via regex, see an example regex here with the [Sklearn random forest](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb).
That being said, **it is often a better idea to separate things and have one model per SageMaker job**, because of the following reasons among other:

1. It allows you to separate model metadata and metrics and compare
   them easily with the [SageMaker metadata service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-now-comes-with-new-capabilities-for-accelerating-machine-learning-experimentation/)
2. It allows you to specialize hardware to each model and get better economics. Each model has its own sweet spot when it comes to CPU, GPU, RAM
3. It allows you to use the exact same container for single training but
   also for [bayesian hyperparameter search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-how-it-works.html), an method that can be
   both faster and cheaper than regular gridsearch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Actually my use case requires multiple model training based on the input just like h2o.ai does. So I need multiple models to train on a dataset and present the metrics so that best model could be chosen and deployed.

Comment: @noswear You can use SageMaker pipelines. It has the conditional branching execution which you can use to pick the best model